# SQL Server 2008 Using SSMS (Creating a Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to creating and designing databases. When you open up SSMS, the first window that will pop up is to connect to a server. My question is the following: I do not want to use a local server, I want to create a server (I am not sure if I am saying that correctly, I am not a technical person) where I and few other people can view my database in that server.

I am tired of not finding what I am looking for (Maybe cause I am not sure how to phrase what I am looking for as all what  I am finding is: How to create tables)

Thank you for any help.

Comment: So to simplify your question you want to create an instance of SQL Server with a database that only authorised people can view/access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A database server is a computer which is running the SQL Server software. You would need a remote computer that you could install SQL server on, and that is what you would connect to. You would then right click on the server and create a new database and tables, as well as user logins/passwords.

From a model perspective, a server can have many databases, and a database can have many tables.

Comment: Yes sir, I understand that. In this case, can I create a server on the cloud? I am not sure how would I do that, but would you please give me any advises about which websites provide this service? and how to connect to the server (if created on the cloud) using SSMS? I am really sorry if my questions are so stupid, I am not a technical person and I am asked to do this at work cause nobody else knows something about programming.

Comment: Not at all, your questions are fine. I suggest taking a look at Windows Azure SQL Database (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/data-management/) for a simple way to get set up with a sql server managed database. It's a Microsoft service and they take care of provisioning, hosting and maintaining your database, and they have plenty of tutorials and documentation as well. I'm sure you'll find what you're looking for there.